# How do I roll around?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain, metal-gear-solid-5-ground-zeroes

In Metal Gear Solid 5: Ground Zeroes/The Phantom Pain, how do I roll using a controller & keyboard and mouse?

Comment: voting down due to the lack of research shown. Another question that is addressed directly in the manual, and again in the games included help files.

Comment: @Timelord64 Funny, isn't it? MGS1 and Metal Gear 2 are literally impossible to beat without looking at the disc case or reading the manual. Yet, here we are 4 main iterations later...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To roll around you need to...

1. Lie down (keep the crouch button pressed)
2. Aim
3. Move either left or right
4. Press the sprint button

You must be moving while pressing the sprint button, and you must be aiming while moving.